# How can I print matrices of different dimensions in a 3D arrangement?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I don't know if you understand me, but I made a 3D array, where each "matrix" has the same rows but different columns:

```java
int nMatrix = 3, rows = 5;
String[][][] matrix = new String[nMatrix][][];
matrix[0] = new String[rows][r.nextInt(3) + 5];
matrix[1] = new String[rows][r.nextInt(3) + 5];
matrix[2] = new String[rows][r.nextInt(3) + 5];
```

I wish I could print this but at the same time:

```
// 5x5 matrix
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]

// 5x7 matrix
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]

// 5x6 matrix
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
for (String[][] x : matrix) {
    for (String[] y : x)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y));
    System.out.println();
}
```

output:

```
[null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null]

[null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

[null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null]
```